# Why was this flag disputed?

Tags: discussion, support, flagging

I flagged [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403443/usb-keyboard-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-04-raring-ringtail/403975#403975) as not an answer, due to it just suggesting a bug report but the flag was disputed.

I understand what a disputed flag is. I am more interested in if I am wrong to flag these type of answers as not an answer.

Am I missing something?, because I would flag this every time for this reason.

Anyone got an opinion on this? I like to flag things correctly, of course.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer "your problem is this bug", specifying the bug by link, is an answer.

It could be better. But deleting it is a much, *much* worse outcome for the op and searchers than just leaving it there.

Comment: It never even occurred to me that this could be the correct answer, I just saw a badly formatted post. I guess I am reading to many of these :) This is a great point and based on this, I have edited the relevant information in to the answer so it can stay. Thanks.